# What statistical analyses should one perform on ensemble forecasts (given a measurement)?

Tags: time-series, ensemble-learning

I have an ensemble of time-series predicting a scalar variable. Additionally, I have a measurement time series of this scalar variable.

Which statistical analyses could and/or should I perform to judge the ensemble predictions?

Answer (score 0):

I have the following on my list, already:

- Distribution of root-mean-square errors (averaged over the time-series)
- Distribution of biases (averaged over the time-series)
- Talagrand histogram (histogram of the location of the measurement with regards to the ensemble members, sorted in ascending order)
- A spread / skill scatter plot and correlation between the two to judge how good uncertainties in the prediction are resembled in the spread of the ensemble